# Why don't git colours appear when using watch?

Tags: git, watch-command

When running `git status -sb` I see:

[image]

I want to `watch` (from procps-ng 3.3.3) a repository. The `--color` option is supposed to keep colours.

---

Interestingly, it works with `ls`:

```
$ watch --color "ls --color"
```

Showing:

[image: output from ls]

---

However for `git` the colours disappear:

```
$ watch --color "git status -sb"
```

[image]

---

So, why does `watch` show colours from `ls` but not from `git` output?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793126/colors-with-unix-command-watch

Comment: @Jobin, thanks, I actually commented at that link before posting this question :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following statements are true:

- `watch` runs the command in a new shell, `sh`.
- `.bashrc` aliases `ls` as `ls --color=auto` to enable colours.
- `sh` doesn't inherit or use `bash` aliases.

So when `watch` runs `ls`, it's not asking for colours, it's just running the plain old version. You can circumvent this but—as aditya points out—you also need to enable colours on `watch` for it to process them properly.

A working example for `ls` is:

```sh
watch --color -- ls --color=always
```

If you don't pass `--color` to watch, you'll see a bunch of ugly colour codes inline.

---

`ls --color` is interpreted as `ls --color=always`.

`ls --color=auto` *does not* print colour in watch. This suggests that it's inferring colour support from the terminal itself.

For more on the reason why, we can [test if the watch shell thinks its a real terminal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/10059/880):

```
$ bash -c '[[ -t 1 ]] && echo "real terminal"'
real terminal

$ watch -- "bash -c '[[ -t 1 ]] && echo "real terminal"'"
# ... nothing.
```

I suspect that some applications are looking at that (or similar) to tell if they should turn on colours or not.

Comment: But the OP wants to know why does this not work with `git status -sb`, even though it works with `ls --color`.

Comment: This makes sense. However there's no alias for `git`. The colouration is [set within git's configuration directly](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13075208/24874). So this doesn't seem to be an aliasing issue.

Comment: Bingo. I'd set my colours to `auto` which, as you correctly surmised, was causing git to avoid the colour output. Using `always` instead has solved this problem. Many thanks!

Answer (score 10):

`git` uses a configuration value to determine whether to show coloured output or not.

For example:

```
git config --global color.ui auto
```

This sets the colour setting to `auto` globally. In `auto` mode, git will determine whether it's a real terminal before sending colour codes, as Oli suggested.

You can force this global value to `always`, however a better idea may be to apply it to a particular command:

```
git -c color.status=always status -sb
```

Putting it all together:

```
watch --color git -c color.status=always status -sb
```

Answer (score 0):

It works if `git` (`--color`) and `watch` (`-c`) are told to use colors:

```
watch -cd "git branch -va --color"
```