# ls system command not showing terminal colors

Tags: c, ls

I've just been fooling around with some code in C, an example of a really basic program is as follows which just, obviously, lists the directories using the ls system command.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    system("ls -l -d */");
    printf("I've just listed the directories :-)\n");
    return 0;
}
```

This runs fine, but it shows the ls output in monochrome, whereas Bash would output the list using colors for the directories (or files if I included files). How can I make my C code use the bash colors? Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ls` is aliased by default as: `ls --color=auto` so when `ls` is in a terminal that supports colour, it uses colour codes.

A `system()` call doesn't happen in a bash session so your aliases aren't evaluated. I'm also not sure what would happen with the automatic detection so I would make it force colourised output by hotwiring the command:

```
system("ls --color=always -l -d */");
```

I've tested that and it works. `--color=auto` worked too and that might be safer.

This phenomenon can happen even without it being in a C `system()` call. I've been through [a similar problem with `watch` with somebody else](https://askubuntu.com/a/423695/449). Run `watch ls -l` and you won't see colours. There's also an explanation on why `--colour=auto` doesn't always work.

Comment: @oli `--color=auto` sets `color_if_tty` which [tries to determine if the current terminal is a tty](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=coreutils.git;a=blob;f=src/ls.c;h=25e10fa74bf0622ae57b1f4e203e2dbdbf5da0f9;hb=HEAD#l1901) before using colors.

Comment: and [here is how](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isatty.3.html): "The isatty() function tests whether fd is an open file descriptor referring to a terminal."