# `watch git log` with correct colors

Tags: command-line, git, colors, watch-command

I want to `watch` the output of `git log --oneline --graph` with all the colors and tried to adapt the solution from [Why don't git colours appear when using watch?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/423672/why-dont-git-colours-appear-when-using-watch), but it just renders (nearly) the whole output in orange:

#### Output using `watch -c`

```
$ watch -c git -c color.diff=always log --graph --oneline
```

[image]

Note how from the first commit hash on everything is printed in orange. This is the output of `watch from procps-ng 3.3.10` on Ubuntu 16.04.

#### Normal output = goal

```
$ git log --graph --oneline
```

[image]

The output with an additional `-c color.diff=always` is the same, `cat -A` shows the ANSI color sequences in use:

```
$ git -c color.diff=always log --graph --oneline | cat -A
* ^[[33m8ccd905^[[m L
* ^[[33me4ad4f6^[[m E
* ^[[33mf427d2a^[[m U
* ^[[33me8351c8^[[m Z
* ^[[33mf06747c^[[m I
```

#### Question

How can I get `watch git log` to show the colors like `git log` does?

Comment: Could you please run the `git` command as you pass it to `watch`, but without `watch`, redirecting its output to a file, and attach/inline the first line? I've just discovered that `watch` doesn't recognize ANSI 39 (reset the foreground color only), I'd like to see whether that's what happens to you too.

Comment: I've found this bug, it was fixed in https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/commit/a5937e4e943eaf28b378a318566d6968f2b167be. I guess you just have an older `watch` version. In Artful it works correctly.

Comment: This one! https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/issues/12

Comment: Yup! (In the mean time I've also filed https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/issues/73.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a [bug](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/issues/12) in `procps-ng` (Ubuntu package name `procps`), [fixed](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/commit/a5937e4e943eaf28b378a318566d6968f2b167be) in version 3.3.11.

Latest Ubuntu LTS (16.04 Xenial) still contains the bug, whereas current regular versions (17.04 Zesty and 17.10 Artful) already ship the fixed version.

Comment: I found a workaround, one can set the colors with the `--pretty` option: `watch -c 'git log --graph --pretty="%C(yellow bold)%h %C(white)%s%C(nobold)"'`. This will print the commit hash in bold yellow and the commit subject in bold white, unfortunately for every line instead of just the first – it's better than no coloring at all though.

Comment: @dessert I'd rather get the fix than introduce workaround: I'd just compile procps from git and place `watch` under my `~/bin`.

Comment: Oh, I didn't think about just replacing `watch`, that's a very good idea. I just saw that the package provides a bunch of quite elementary commands one should really not mess around with and gave up updating because of that – thanks!

Comment: I just updated `watch` and tried it, but it still doesn't work correctly! `git log` shows the first line bold, `watch` doesn't. Is this yet another color sequence `watch` doesn't understand (yet)?

Comment: The escape sequences you showed above switch to yellow (often brown) (`^[[33m`) but not bold. `git` often does things differently depending on whether its output is a terminal. Compare the look of `watch -c git ...` with the same git options in `git ... | cat` (this forces its standard output not to be a terminal). If they do the same, that is, piping through `cat` doesn't produce the desired result, you should look around in git's configuration.

Comment: I wondered about this already when posting the question, but I assumed this would be normal behaviour – turns out it's not, my terminal is just set to print everything bold, so until the first reset the output of `git log` is also bold.

Comment: However, as I consider this very useful – it shows the commit you're able to change with `--amend` – I recreate this behaviour using `watch -c -- 'tput bold && git log'` now.

Answer (score 2):

The comment by [egmont](https://askubuntu.com/questions/967503/watch-git-log-with-correct-colors#comment1549250_967503) tells about `watch` not recognizing ANSI 39 (reset the foreground color only). It is `^[[39m` as pointed by [WJAndrea](https://askubuntu.com/questions/967503/watch-git-log-with-correct-colors/997009?noredirect=1#comment1610730_997009). Others have answered that it is a bug in `procps-ng`.

In other git commands, like `diff`, it is noticeable that bold colors work, but any uncolored text that follows keeps the previous color, until a new bold color appears. The reason is that bold colors specify '^[[`1;`##m'.

So we known where to focus.

First I made a quick regex with `sed` to replace all colors to bold, and was working just fine. It just required a leading bold color, because some git commands output do not start colored and there were a starting regular text until the first color code.

I tested during this afternoon, and that massive bold text was taking my attention.

> I use [i3wm](https://i3wm.org/), so I keep some terminals open side by side. And one vivid and colorful terminal watching my git log was starting to be annoying. Before today I was living with a uncolored log :c

Another problem is that I hard-coded a bold light gray color to replace the uncolored text: people using other color schemes could yell at me.

To solve all, I changed my initial idea to something simpler. Instead of bolding the text, I just need to add a `0` to make the color code valid to `watch`. Changed a few characters and voilà! The colors appear as expected, bold texts keep their meaning, and the window hanging around feels better.

I tested the performance with a huge commit history (>90k commits), and there is a noticeable delay of some milliseconds, if you use the `--graph` or `--date-order` flags, and maybe others, but `--oneline` seems safe. Even asking to log only a few commits gives delay, Git has to process the whole history to generate the graph.

But that case was extreme. And you don't need a 0.1s update. 3 or 4s looks good. `watch -n #`

My current code is the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
git -c color.ui=always "$@" | sed -r $'s/\033\[([[:digit:]][[:digit:]])m/\033\[0;\\1m/g; s/\033\[m/\033\[0m/g'
```

I saved in `~/bin/git-colored` with +x permission and it can be used with `git colored <git command>`

Solving the main post: `watch -c 'git colored log --oneline --graph'`

I created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/aryelgois/c413ca5bf7bb9341c3c9181d492217d6) with this file, where you can see the code history.

**TL;DR**

There is a bug in a Ubuntu package. The one line code above is a workaround for who can not/don't want to upgrade the system, basically doing what is in [here](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/commit/a5937e4e943eaf28b378a318566d6968f2b167be).

Comment: "ANSI 39" means `^[[39m`

Comment: Oh I see.. it resets only the foreground color. But in my regex, I am using `^[[0m`, which resets all attributes. This does not seem to be a problem, right?

Answer (score 1):

A quick workaround I made if you don't have procps-ng 3.3.11: pipe your git output through `sed "s/\x1b\[m/\x1b\[00m/"`, e.g. for `git status`:

```
watch -c 'git -c color.ui=always status | sed "s/\x1b\[m/\x1b\[00m/"'
```

This replaces empty ANSI escapes (`[m`, not recognized by `watch`) with zeroed ones (`[00m`, fully recognized by `watch`).